# React.js + webpack: build own library for several projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have react.js application that is built by webpack. Inside this project, I have some components that I wish to reuse in another react.js project. At the very beginning, I just made copy-paste. However, I realize that it was a bad idea because these components are alive and updated from time to time. And after each update, I wish to have the same changes in another project. So the solution is obvious, I have to make some lib which will contain my components that all project should depend on this lib. The question is how to make such kind of lib?
In view I a newbie in react and webpack, it would be nice to have step instruction or link where I can find some kinda tutorial

Comment: You will have to separate out the component into its own project and then package it with npm.

Google `react component npm package` and you'll find articles on it like this one: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) to do just that. This allows you to develop locally and include local packages as you would a package on the npm registry.

Comment: Is there a way to do the with webpack?

Comment: You could use and alias, but I would still recommend yarn workspaces. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias